# load a file content with spaces in file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var path = 'nts/test_01.txt';
div.load(path); // this works

var path = 'nts/test 01.txt';
div.load(path); // error - the file doesn't exists
```

Obviously a space is the problem.
How to solve this?
I can't change the file name.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

encode the string

```
 var path = 'nts/test 01.txt';
 var path1 = encodeURI(path); //encodes string space fills with %20
 div.load(path1);
```

**OR**

replace space

```
var path = './test 01.txt';
var path1 = path.replace(/ /g,"%20"); //Replace space fills with %20
div.load(path1)
```

tested both methods it works charm you can try any of them both work perfectly.

Comment: and loaded is nothing. file name is not without spaces, but with spaces

Answer (score 0):

You need to *escape* spaces: `var path = 'nts/test\ 01.txt'`

Comment: path is a variable, can be `lorem ipsum 01.txt`, or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually you can use %20 to represent a space:

```
var path = 'nts/test%2001.txt';
```

or you can use [encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) function